How to prevent Clang-format to not break line for double quotes?
How to prevent Clang-format break line?
sprintf(body,
            "<html><title>Tiny Error</title><body bgcolor="
            "ffffff"
            ">\r\n");

I want to use like:
sprintf(body, "<html><title>Tiny Error</title><body bgcolor=""ffffff"">\r\n");

my clang_format_style is { BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 2, TabWidth: 2, ColumnLimit: 180, AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None }
